# How to get url of multiple selected file in ckfinder

Tags: ckfinder

I am using ckfinder for file manager of my website.
I used [this post](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/SelectFunction) for get url of selectd file.
but how can I access to url of multiple selected files in ckfinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use third argument of select `finder.SelectFunction` handler:

```
function showFileInfo( fileUrl, file, files ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
        console.log( files[i].url );
    }
}
```

With this you also get whole array of selected files which contains information about file like name, size, etc.